# Easticsearch stopping with outofmemory

Tags: elasticsearch, elastic-stack

We are setting up ELK for our enterprise and everything is setup.
The hardware / software configuration is as follows:

Total RAM - 192G
JDK = Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM

for injecting the datafiles we are using Logstash filebeat plugin and the indices are built properly and things seems to be working properly until we got the following error

```
java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: unable to create new native thread
        at java.lang.Thread.start0(Native Method) ~[?:1.8.0_144]
        at java.lang.Thread.start(Thread.java:717) ~[?:1.8.0_144]
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.addWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:957) ~[?:1.8.0_144]
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.processWorkerExit(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1025) ~[?:1.8.0_144]
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1167) ~[?:1.8.0_144]
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624) ~[?:1.8.0_144]
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748) [?:1.8.0_144]
```

first the impression was that it could have been caused by the narrow `-Xms` and `-Xmx` setting and we changed it to `20g`

but the problems persists. The Elasticsearch starts normally, rebuilds the indices and then ...

Based on a few threads - we tried the following:

1. Changed the the `Xss` setting in jvm.options file from `1m` to `228k`
2. Increased the ulimit to `65536`

but, nothing seems to work.

Answer (score 1):

This has nothing to do with heap, as the error message indicates, that the JVM is not able to create a native operating system thread. Please ensure via `ulimit` that new processes can be started.

On the other hand, this could also show a misconfiguration (i.e. wrong configured threadpools that try to spawn too many threads).

Answer (score 0):

You may try increasing Xmx to 30GB. Also enable JMX on elasticsearch jvm to check which is consuming more space on heap.

Wondering, how many indices you have and its how much disk space those indices occupy?

Answer (score 0):

I agree that it has nothing to with the heapsize as 20g is more than enough for any decent application and also the error shows `unable to create new native thread`

I problem was solved (as of now) by changing the 'max user processes' from `1024` to `65536`